# Using multiple bootstrap buttons with jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using multiple bootstrap buttons, each to delete a specific items from a database using jquery ajax. Here is some sample HTML.

```
 <form name = "reply" id="replyForm" ><tr>
        <td><a href="projectdetails.php?id=vofQxri7mZvW1nsdpUZuaQDMIws82OOX">Demo</a></td>
        <td>Internal Projects <input type="hidden" name="id" value="vofQxri7mZvW1nsdpUZuaQDMIws82OOX"></td>
        <td><button id = "newThread" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Delete</button></td></form>
        </tr>
 <form name = "reply" id="replyForm" ><tr>
        <td><a href="projectdetails.php?id=lYQPeqRzrwjjOpd7dgsLMf5IP2vBqZKV">Demo1 Project</a></td>
        <td>Demo Client <input type="hidden" name="id" value="lYQPeqRzrwjjOpd7dgsLMf5IP2vBqZKV"></td>
        <td><button id = "newThread" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Delete</button></td></form>
```

I am using the following Javascript to sent information to the server

```
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default click action

        var $form = $('#replyForm');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delproject.php',
            type: 'Post',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                alert(data);
                // ajax success callback
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('ajax failed');
                // ajax error callback
            },
        });
    });
```

There is no data being sent to the server. I think this is because the form is not being picked up by Ajax. How can I ensure the correct data is sent to the server?

Thanks

Comment: Does the chrome console show any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to grab the specific form that your button belongs to. Currently your `$form` variable is grabbing both forms on your page, which you don't want.

So change this:

```
var $form = $('#replyForm');
```

To this:

```
var $form = $(this).parent('form');
```

Now when you click a button, it grabs just the one form it belongs to, which is then serialized and sent.

Here a demo: https://jsbin.com/wesutajebe/1/edit?html,js,output. Click the Delete buttons and you'll see the correct form data being serialized.

Side note: it's usually not a good idea to have multiple forms (or any elements for that matter) with the same ID.

And actually, if you just have this one `id` variable to send to the server, forms in general are a bit overkill. Here's a different approach that you might find simpler:

https://jsbin.com/vurajogaye/1/edit?html,js,output

I've removed all the form tags and even the hidden inputs. The buttons themselves have the ID you need. And the javascript handler uses the simpler jQuery `post` method.

Comment: Thanks Jszobody, instead if using forms, what is a better way to pass the ID to the server?

Comment: @user813813 see my updated answer. not sure if this will work for you or not, but it's what I would do. whole lot simpler.